# How to enable php5.5 Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I installed `Homebrew` and decided to upgrade php version to 5.5. Make it through the command:

```
brew install php55
```

All went well, and then I ordered a .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php55)/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Next in the directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/ I created info.php file:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And opened it through the browser, but display the old version of php 5.4.30. How to enable php5.5 or delete old version php5.4.30? Help me!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, in the Apache configuration file `nttpd.conf` was need to set the path to the new version of php:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```